# how to store pointers in map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I am working on one of the project which requires

```
class MyObj;

map<string, MyObj*> myMap;
```

Here logic is here to map file name to MyObj class.

If I try to insert following

```
string strFilename = "MyFile";
MyObj* pObj  = new MyObj();

myMap.insert(strFileName, pObj); // This line throwing following error.
```

> no matching function for call to `'std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, void*, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, void*> > >::insert(std::string&, void*)'`

Can any one please help me how to solve this. Are is there better way we can do this using STL

Comment: Use the toolbar buttons above the text field to control the formatting of your question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've typedef'd this stuff to make it more readable...

```
typedef std::map<std::string, MyObj*> MyMap;
typedef std::pair<std::string, MyObj*> MyPair;

MyMap myMap;
string strFilename = "MyFile";
MyObj* pObj = new MyObj();
myMap.insert(MyPair(strFilename, pObj));
```

Answer (score 18):

std::map requires a pair when you use the insert function.

You have two options, either:

```
myMap[strFileName] = pObj;
```

Or:

```
myMap.insert(std::make_pair(strFileName,pObj));
```

Answer (score 8):

> myMap.insert(strFileName, pObj);

Use [`make_pair()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/make_pair/) inside `insert()`

```
#include <utility>
//...
myMap.insert (std::make_pair(strFileName, pObj) ) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `insert` member that takes a key and a value as arguments. Just use the index operator:

```
myMap[fileName] = obj;
```

Comment: It is not true. `insert` exists. See Prasoon answer

Comment: It is true. Prasoon's answer confirms what I said: There is no `insert` that takes a key and a value as arguments. His answer uses the insert that takes one `std::pair<key,value>` as its sole argument.

Answer (score 4):

```
map<string,MyObj*> myMap;

string strFilename = "MyFile";  
MyObj* pObj = new MyObj();

myMap[strFilename] = pObj;
```

Should work just fine.
Just remember clearing the map wont free up the memory the pointers are pointing to.

Answer (score 3):

Insert wants a pair, try something like this:

```
mymap.insert ( pair<string,MyObj*>(strFilename,pObj) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try boost::ptr_map (from boost::ptr_container library). And with boost::assign library you even do not need to call new manually:

```
class MyObj {
    MyObj() { /* some... */ }
};

typedef boost::ptr_map< string, MyObj > MyMap;
MyMap m;

using namespace boost::assign;

ptr_map_insert( m )( "first" )( "second" )( "third" );
```

In this case three elements will added in m (with keys "first", "second" and "third" and with three created objects MyObj()).

Or:

```
class MyObj {
    MyObj( int _i ) : i( _i ) { /* some... */ }
    int i;
};

typedef boost::ptr_map< string, MyObj > MyMap;
MyMap m;

using namespace boost::assign;

ptr_map_insert( m )( "first", 1 )( "second", 2 )( "third", 3 );
```

In this case three elements will added in m. First element have key "first" and value MyObj( 1 ), second - key "second" and MyObj( 2 ), third - key "third" and MyObj( 3 ).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `insert()` incorrectly.  It does not take a key and a value separately, it takes a pair like this:

```
myMap.insert(pair < string, MyObj* > (strFileName, pObj));
```

Comment: That won't compile, pair is a template class

Comment: I keep forgetting that < and > need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Try boost::ptr_map ()

Answer (score 0):

[emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) inserts a new element into the container constructed in-place with the given args if there is no element with the key in the container.

```
myMap.emplace(strFileName, pObj);
```